# Shoping cart M2M model with items count in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, shopping-cart

I'm trying to create shopping cart system for one of mine pet project.

I have `Profile` model that is an extension for built-in `User` model. My `Profile` model has `shopping_cart` field which is M2M relationship to `Clothing` model from another app, which represents my product. In code, `Profile` model looks like this:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="profile")

    ...
    shopping_cart = models.ManyToManyField(
        to=Clothing,
        related_name="shopping_cart",
        blank=True
    )
```

To add new item to `shopping_cart` field I use `request` object that has `user` object which in turn has `profile` that I need:

> request.user.profile.shopping_cart.add(item)

So, I want to let user add multiple instances of the same item to `shoping_cart`, and then just count how many and what items do user has in his `shopping_cart`, probably, with `Counter` from `collections`.

Then, if I added let's say, 3 items to `shopping_cart`, I expecting output like this (with `Counter` from `collections`):

> Counter({`<Clothing: 14VQv52T2409iXGC7958>`: 3})

But I got this:

> Counter({`<Clothing: 14VQv52T2409iXGC7958>`: 1})

---

Now, who can explain why this happens, because I thought M2M means I can add multiple instances of same item, and it will display ALL added items.

---

UPD 1:
Intermediate model:

```
class ShoppingCart(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(to=Clothing, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    in_profile = models.ForeignKey(to="Profile", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    count = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(
        default=1,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item.title
```

Part where I proceeding request:

```
def proceed_request(self, request):
    item = Clothing.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("id"))
    related_field = request.user.profile.shopping_cart
    if item and item in related_field.all():
        related_field.count() += 1 # Throws 'SyntaxError: can't assign to function call' error.
        related_field.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, f"{item.title} has successfully uppdated!")
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    related_field.add(item)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, f"{item.title} has successfully added to {self.verbose_field_name}!")
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

UPD 2:
Updated `proceed_request` function. now all works well.

```
def proceed_request(self, request):
    item = Clothing.objects.get(pk=request.POST.get("id"))
    related_model = request.user.profile.shopping_cart
    if item and item in related_model.all():
        cart_item = ShoppingCart.objects.get(item=item)
        cart_item.count += 1
        cart_item.save()
        messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, f"{item.title} has successfully uppdated!")
        return HttpResponse(status=200)
    ShoppingCart.objects.create(item=item, in_profile=request.user.profile)
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, f"{item.title} has successfully added to {self.verbose_model_name}!")
    return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Answer (score 1):

With M2M you can add multiple *different* items of Clothing, but adding the same item multiple times will not duplicate the relation.  Have a look at adding a `count` field to the relation by using `through`:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: okay, i tested this a bit, but how i can increment `count` field? when i'm trying to add 1 to itself it throws an error: "SyntaxError: can't assign to function call". also updated post with current code.

Comment: You want `related_field.count += 1`.  It is an attribute, not a method.

Comment: Updated question. Your example throws `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'method' and 'int'`.

Comment: I can't see why you would get that error.  I think I'd need to see the full code.